# Hadoop - Reduce the number of Spilled Records

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have an Ubuntu vm running in stand alone/pseudo mode with 4gb ram and 4 cores.

Everything is set to default except:

```
io.file.buffer.size=65536
io.sort.factor=50
io.sort.mb=500
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=4
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=4
```

This ofc will not be a production machine but I am fiddling with it to get the grips with the fine tuning.

My problem is that when I run my benchmark Hadoop Streaming job (get distinct records over a 1.8gb text file) I get quite a lot of spilled records and the above tweaks don't seem to reduce the spills. Also I have noticed that when I monitor the memory usage in the Ubuntu's System Monitor it never gets fully used and never goes above 2.2gb.

I have looked at chaging `HADOOP_HEAP`, `mapred.map.child.java.opts` and `mapred.reduce.child.java.opts` but I am not sure what to set these to as the defaults seem as though they should be enough.

Is there a setting I am missing that will allow Hadoop to utilise the remaining ram therefore reduce spilled records (hopefully speeding up jobs) or is this normal behaviour?

Many Thanks!

Comment: These slides helped me. It's very well explained. Please have a look: http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/mr-perf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to increasing memory, have you considered if you can run a combiner for your task after the map step, which will compress and reduce the amount of records that need to be kept in memory or spilled?

Unfortunately when you are using streaming, seems that this has to be coded in Java, and can't be in whatever language you're using.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming

Comment: Looks like this limitation has been lifted in the latest versions of Hadoop. The Help now reads:

 -combiner       <cmd|JavaClassName> Optional. Command to be run as combiner

Answer (score 1):

The default memory assigned to map/reduce task is 200mb. You can increase that value with -Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx512M

Anyway, this is a very interesting material about hadoop tunning [Hadoop Performance](http://www.scribd.com/doc/23046928/Hadoop-Performance-Tuning)

Hope it helps!